# Unexpected behavior testing the results of multiple function calls in an if statement

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following, very simple block of code:

```
<script>
function hasVal(field) {
    console.log(field);
    var ret = false;

    return ret;
}

if(hasVal('#field1') && hasVal('#field2')) {
    console.log('here');
}else {
    console.log('there');
}
</script>
```

I was expecting it to output the following:

```
#field1
#field2
there
```

What it actually outputs is:

```
#field1
there
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Does Javascript stop evaluating the rest of the `if` statement as soon as it gets `false` back from the first function call?

Comment: Why do you think it would need to run the second half if the first half is already known to fail? It is like driving to the store to go shopping when you know the store is already closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators have what's sometimes called **short-circuit** behavior, so yes, the evaluation of `&&` stops as soon as an operand is `false`.

Similarly, evaluation of `||` is finished as soon as an operand is `true`.

This is usually a tremendous benefit to you as a programmer, though there are rare cases (most of which bear significant code smells, like the side-effects in your example) when you do want complete evaluation. For that you can use the plain boolean `&` and `|`, or else explicitly decompose your expression into separate statements.

The reason it's such a good thing can be seen in the extremely common case of having to check whether something is `null` (or otherwise not available) before accessing a property:

```
if (something != null && something.whatever == 17) {
  ...
}
```

If the `&&` were always to evaluate both sides of the expression, that idiom would not work, and our lives as software developers would be even more hellish.

Comment: Fascinating. I feel silly that I've never run into this before. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: (For the record, I'm fixing a nasty bug in someone else's Javascript.)

Comment: Well it's always a learning experience working on problems in code you didn't write. :-)  (In fact that's why Stackoverflow itself is so educational!)

Answer (score 1):

Because your second condition in `if` does not execute. For `&&` to work **both** left and right conditions should resolve to **truthy** value. Interpreter sees that first condition is `false`, it skips second one straight away since it wasn't truthy.